# Simple drag 'n' drop element motion is jerky

Tags: javascript, user-interface

Please take a look here [jsFiddle Mock-up](http://jsfiddle.net/V2ePj/)

Move the orange square around. It should be very jerky.
Change `left: 0` for the track and there's no problem.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.pageX` is position on the screen but `this.style.left` is position inside of `div track`

Answer (score 0):

The `pageX` value is relative to the left edge of the document, not the handle. Change `var h = e.pageX;` to `var h = e.pageX - 100;`. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V2ePj/1/).